# Is It Possible to get Latitutde and Longitude From GPS without using Internet?

Tags: android, gps

I am developing one application in that I want to get latitude and longitude from gps only without connect internet. I tried but unable get lat lng value zeros when wifi off. If  wifi on I am getting correct lat long values. Is It Possible getting lat long values only from gps without connecting to  Internet ?

My Code

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener{

    LocationManager locationManager ;
    String provider;

    private String strAdd;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      //  requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      //  getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.custom_title);

        // Getting LocationManager object
        locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);


            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        //    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 10, 30, this);

            if(location!=null){
                onLocationChanged(location);
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Location can't be retrieved",   
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // Getting reference to TextView tv_longitude
        TextView tvLongitude = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);


        // Getting reference to TextView tv_latitude
        //TextView tvLatitude = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_latitude);

        // Setting Current Longitude
        double lat = location.getLatitude();
        double lng = location.getLongitude();

      Log.e("LAT LNG", lat+lng+"");
        tvLongitude.setText("LAT LNG:" + lat+lng);



        // Setting Current Latitude
       // tvLatitude.setText("Latitude:" + location.getLatitude() );
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

Comment: Downvoters would also like to explain for downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, absolutely.

The GPS radio has nothing to do with the Internet. There are plenty of GPS devices that have no Internet capability. The inverse is also true, there are also plenty of devices that have no true GPS radio, but still provide location information via the network provider.

If using GPS_PROVIDER and ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, LONG and LAT should come from the GPS receiver, usually in NMEA format (protocol). The "Internet" is used to add coarse, supplementary location via AGPS, Wifi triangulation, cellular network, etc. however, true GPS is still GPS radio based.

Check that your app permissions include:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

If the device has a GPS radio, then Internet connectivity is not *required* for GPS. If the device has no GPS radio, then it will need the network to fake GPS. Even then, it isn't "GPS" it is AGPS or Wifi triangulation or cell triangulation.

There are 32 GPS satellites in constellation around the earth, hence the "Global" in "Global Positioning System". GPS isn't based on access to a service. It is based on trilateration, which only requires a radio on the device, and "line of sight" to 3 or 4 of the 32 satellites. It measures the time delay of signals of the 4 satellites and can be accurate to within a couple of meters. If it is based on anything else, it is "Assisted" GPS of some sort and is a coarse location.

In practice, it is often preferable to use AGPS for fast-start tracking, or as a fallback, because true GPS waypoints can take a bit to lock, or not lock at all if there is obstruction, and in some cases, any location is better than none. On the other hand, there may be cases where you only want a true GPS location, such as in law enforcement. Should we trigger an ankle-cuff alert based on a Wifi router that is across the street, hundreds of feet away from the house / geofence that an offender is confined to?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You need to connect to the GPS provider in LocationManager and requestUpdates for it.  Do not use criteria, explicitly request GPS.  Make sure that you have the FINE location permission.

You can't use getLastKnownLocation like that.  There may not be a location yet, in which case it can return null or invalid data.  You must call requestUpdates or requestSingleUpdate and wait for Android to get a location lock and call onLocationChanged.  getLastKnownLocation should never be relied upon.  It only really works if something else is already using GPS, or if you have a network location it can fall back to.

Comment: I tried like this locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
 Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

Comment: But the lat lng always comes with zeros only

Comment: Post the code you're using, including your onLocationUpdate function, because it shouldn't be.

Comment: Updated my answer.  Unfortunately you tried taking the easy way out and it isn't going to work.

Comment: the toast is coming "Location can't be retrieved"

Comment: Yup.  That's what's expected when you call getLastKnownLocation and it doesn't have a valid location already-  it returns null.

Comment: Ya removed getLastknowLocation() instead of that i wrote  locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);   locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10, 30, this);

Comment: Still i am not getting any thing